# show background color when print page

Tags: html, css, printing

i have page that print report from my site, and i set the table for show grid result.

So, my problem is, i set for `th` attrbute table background color, this background is show on page before print it, But when print it, the `th` background not show.

here my css code :-

```
@media print {
.head th {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#CCCCCC), to(#CCCCCC));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #CCCCCC,  #CCCCCC);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
    }
    }
.wrap{
     width: auto; 
     background:#fff;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     margin:30px;
}
th {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#CCCCCC), to(#CCCCCC));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #CCCCCC,  #CCCCCC);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
}
```

how can i show the `th` backgound when i print this page.

Comment: in your browser make sure that print background color & images option is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to have a look at `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` to enable your browser print colored background...

valuses:

**economy**
Normal behavior.  Background colors and images are only printed if the user explicitly allows it in their browser's print settings dialog.

**exact**
Background colors and images of the element to which this rule is applied are always printed, user's print settings are overridden.

hope this helps

Comment: thank you, another questions, how can i remove the page number and date from print page without change any thing from browser

Comment: when you press CTR+P (try to print you page) wizard will popup, this wizard is php, java or any stuff, important think for you is that whole page is Html or css, try to inspect element and play with css on it I think that it could be edited by CSS `@page {
margin: value;
}` ... sorry I never wanted something like that...